# Change group using regex java

Tags: java, regex

I need help in regular expression using in regex java.

I need change group in string:

Example:

**Input:**

```
=sum($var1;2) or =if($result<10;"little";"big") ...
```

**Need Output:**

```
=sum(teste;2) or =if(teste<10;"little";"big") ...
```

Code I have:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\.*)(\\$\\w)(\\.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(total);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.replaceAll("$2teste"));
}
```

**Output I have:**

```
=sum($vtestear1;2)
=if($r testeesultado<5;"maior";"menor")
```

Comment: `Pattern.compile("([$]\\w+)")` and `m.replaceAll("teste")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why match everything when all you need is to match variable tokens?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b\\$[a-z0-9]+\\b");
p.matcher(total).replaceAll("teste");
```

Change the `[a-z0-9]` part if you can have more than lowercase ASCII letters and digits.

Also, you don't need to test for `.find()` or anything if you `.replace()`: no match means nothing will be replaced.